# How can this dereference a possible null pointer?

Tags: java, netbeans

```
public void printSomething (Doggy console, Catty dialog) {
    if (console == null && dialog == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException ("Both console and dialog were null."); 
    }
    else if (console != null && dialog != null) {
        throw new RuntimeException ("Both console and dialog were created.");
    }
    else {
        if (console != null) {
            console.getInfo ("some String");
        }
        else {
            dialog.getInfo ("Some String"); 
        }
    }
```

I don't get why this would be dereferencing a possible null pointer warning as arguably I justified via my two preconditions that either console or dialog is null. Also, is there a better way to write this? The only realy solution I have is doing this in the else statement.

```
     if (console != null) {
       console.getInfo ("some String");
     }
     else if (dialog != null) {
       dialog.getInfo ("some String");
     }
     else {
        throw new RuntimeException ("Couldn't grab info."); 
     }
```

On a side note I should point out that console dialog or two different versions of a UI that implement a interface and all getInfo does is grab a string and then prints out the info in the appropriate UI.

Comment: What gives you this warning?

Comment: @greyfairer netbeans does.

Comment: This is why many people at SO ask repeatedly for (1) the actual error message you get, with stacktrace if possible, (2) executable code.  In your case, it would be trivial to write code to exercise your method, and I'm confident you would discover that it works fine.  Your problem is somewhere else.  Stay aware that, if you don't know WHAT the problem is, you might be better off giving us a more general description instead of just those parts you suspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netbeans or any other static code analysis tool cannot 100% predict your control flow, so there will allways be some 'false positives'.

That being said, the following should be simple enough to be correctly analyzed by netbeans.

```
if (console != null && dialog != null){
    throw new RuntimeException ("Both console and dialog were created."); 
}
else if (console != null){
    console.getInfo ("some String");

}
else if (dialog != null){
    dialog.getInfo ("some String");

}
else {
    throw new RuntimeException ("Both console and dialog were null."); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it's the last condition check that's a nested else statement that then uses the dialog variable to call getInfo on that's causing your possible null pointer. Of course your program will never actually be null at that point, but the nesting structure apparently is throwing Netbeans for a loop. I like @greyfairer's answer to this, but this small change would probably fix your problem too:

```
public void printSomething (Doggy console, Catty dialog) {
    if (console == null && dialog == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException ("Both console and dialog were null."); 
    }
    else if (console != null && dialog != null) {
        throw new RuntimeException ("Both console and dialog were created.");
    }
    else {
        if (console != null) {
            console.getInfo ("some String");
        }
        else if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.getInfo ("Some String"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No NPE is thrown in the posted code.

The rest is broken into sections,  each dealing with one if block.  sections is for clarity,  since my answer seems to run together otherwise...

**first if block**

```
if (console == null && dialog == null) {
```

truth table:

```
> console  dialog  result
> valid     valid  if body skipped
> valid     null   if body skipped
> null      valid  if body skipped
> null      null   if body entered; function exited
```

**second if block**

```
else if (console != null && dialog != null) {
```

only triggers if both are non null.

```
  console  dialog  result
  valid    valid   if body entered; exception thrown
  valid    null    if body skipped
  valid    null    if body skipped
  null     null    impossible; would have been caught ny first if statement
```

**third if block**

```
    if (console != null) {
```

```
dialog  console  result
valid   valid   impossible,  woukd be caught by second block
valid   null    skips if body
null    valid   enters if body
null    null    impossible,  caught by first if
```

**else,  triggered only if all the other blocks have failed. to catch the null condition.**

```
    else {
        dialog.getInfo ("Some String");
```

the only condition left is if dialog is valid and console is null.   No NPE will be thrown.

Comment: In your last truth table you have the only condition left as dialog =valid and console=null, which isn't dialog being null.

Comment: @sage88 you are correct.   misread my own truth tables :-)  fixing.